# add block drop-down link(menu) on quick access link on header of magento

Tags: magento

I want to add a new drop-down links(menu) on header links(quick access) and move links of  on it
just when a customer sign in show this drop-down links on quick access and it does not show when customer is guest or log out and when customer log in show name of customer as topic of drop-down links .
for this scenario what do I do now? I make static block for drop-down block and remove log out, my wishlist ,my account from top.links on page.xml and call static block on header but I do not know how to avoid to show for all customer(gust or log in) and another way that I test  I want to call static block on local.xml in tag   but I do not how to call static block
another problem on static block I cant use php code and I do not use getWelcome() ?> for topic of drop-down links.

Comment: Can you provide a markup (image) of what your tying to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use php code inside static block so you need to create your own template file.
2. If you create you own template file you can use:

   ```
   <?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
       //put Welcome message with $this->getWelcome() or anything you needed
       <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_indentifer')->toHtml() ?>
   <?php else: ?>
      //if needed, display something for not logged-in usersY here 
    <?php endif; ?>
   ```
3. You can also use `<customer_logged_in></customer_logged_in>` node in your local.xml instead of isLoggedIn() method in order to add you .phtml template or statick block (please note that it's top-level node and shouldn't been wrapped in `<default>` node)

Comment: I don't make template now , I want to know make template file like u said and save with .phtml and call on header.phtml?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you, but yes, seems legit

Comment: about second solution : I made static block and call block on header.phtml (  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('test')->toHtml() ?>) but in <customer_logged_in></customer_logged_in> how reference this block, but show the block all the time